# Wordpress ACF add row to flexible content programmatically

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, acfpro

I want to add a row to my posts flexible content field.
I create my ACF fields using the code from the export tool, this is a part of it:

```
acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'group_5c4c39a08349a',
        'title' => 'Posts page',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_5c4c39aab1ed4',
                'label' => 'Blokken positie',
                'name' => 'block_position',
                'type' => 'radio',
                'instructions' => 'Geef aan waar de pagina blokken geplaatst moeten worden',
                'required' => 1,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                'choices' => array(
                    0 => 'Boven de berichten',
                    1 => 'Onder de berichten',
                ),
                'allow_null' => 0,
                'other_choice' => 0,
                'default_value' => 1,
                'layout' => 'vertical',
                'return_format' => 'value',
                'save_other_choice' => 0,
            ),
        ),
        'location' => array(
            array(
                array(
                    'param' => 'page_type',
                    'operator' => '==',
                    'value' => 'posts_page',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'menu_order' => 6,
        'position' => 'normal',
        'style' => 'default',
        'label_placement' => 'top',
        'instruction_placement' => 'label',
        'hide_on_screen' => '',
        'active' => true,
        'description' => '',
    ));

    acf_add_local_field_group(array(
        'key' => 'group_5c4a061a6be68',
        'title' => 'Page/ Post blocks',
        'fields' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'field_5c4a0645c3baa',
                'label' => 'Blocks',
                'name' => 'blocks',
                'type' => 'flexible_content',
                'instructions' => '',
                'required' => 0,
                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                'wrapper' => array(
                    'width' => '',
                    'class' => '',
                    'id' => '',
                ),
                'layouts' => array(
                    'layout_5c4a084c7953b' => array(
                        'key' => 'layout_5c4a084c7953b',
                        'name' => 'news_slider',
                        'label' => 'Nieuws slider',
                        'display' => 'block',
                        'sub_fields' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5c4a085f7953e',
                                'label' => 'Type',
                                'name' => 'type',
                                'type' => 'select',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                                'wrapper' => array(
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'choices' => array(
                                    0 => 'Laatste berichten',
                                    1 => 'Berichten uit een categorie',
                                    2 => 'Zelf de berichten selecteren',
                                ),
                                'default_value' => array(
                                ),
                                'allow_null' => 0,
                                'multiple' => 0,
                                'ui' => 0,
                                'return_format' => 'value',
                                'ajax' => 0,
                                'placeholder' => '',
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5c4ac2d1986b9',
                                'label' => 'Aantal nieuws artikelen',
                                'name' => 'news_items',
                                'type' => 'number',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => array(
                                    array(
                                        array(
                                            'field' => 'field_5c4a085f7953e',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => '0',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                    array(
                                        array(
                                            'field' => 'field_5c4a085f7953e',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => '1',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'wrapper' => array(
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'default_value' => 9,
                                'placeholder' => '',
                                'prepend' => '',
                                'append' => '',
                                'min' => 3,
                                'max' => 18,
                                'step' => 3,
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5c4a093b2ba54',
                                'label' => 'Toon nieuws uit categorie',
                                'name' => 'news_category',
                                'type' => 'taxonomy',
                                'instructions' => '',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => array(
                                    array(
                                        array(
                                            'field' => 'field_5c4a085f7953e',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => '1',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'wrapper' => array(
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'taxonomy' => 'category',
                                'field_type' => 'select',
                                'allow_null' => 0,
                                'add_term' => 1,
                                'save_terms' => 0,
                                'load_terms' => 0,
                                'return_format' => 'object',
                                'multiple' => 0,
                            ),
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5c4a09e7ee82f',
                                'label' => 'Selecteer nieuws berichten',
                                'name' => 'news_item_collection',
                                'type' => 'repeater',
                                'instructions' => 'De slider laat 3 items per slide zien. Zorg dat het aantal items deelbaar is door 3.',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => array(
                                    array(
                                        array(
                                            'field' => 'field_5c4a085f7953e',
                                            'operator' => '==',
                                            'value' => '2',
                                        ),
                                    ),
                                ),
                                'wrapper' => array(
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'collapsed' => '',
                                'min' => 0,
                                'max' => 0,
                                'layout' => 'table',
                                'button_label' => '',
                                'sub_fields' => array(
                                    array(
                                        'key' => 'field_5c4a0a08ee830',
                                        'label' => 'Nieuws item',
                                        'name' => 'news_item',
                                        'type' => 'post_object',
                                        'instructions' => '',
                                        'required' => 0,
                                        'conditional_logic' => 0,
                                        'wrapper' => array(
                                            'width' => '',
                                            'class' => '',
                                            'id' => '',
                                        ),
                                        'post_type' => array(
                                            0 => 'post',
                                        ),
                                        'taxonomy' => '',
                                        'allow_null' => 0,
                                        'multiple' => 0,
                                        'return_format' => 'object',
                                        'ui' => 1,
                                    ),
                                ),
                            ),
                        ),
                        'min' => '',
                        'max' => '',
                    ),
                    'layout_5c4a065576f71' => array(
                        'key' => '5c4a065576f71',
                        'name' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Tekst (1 blok per rij)',
                        'display' => 'block',
                        'sub_fields' => array(
                            array(
                                'key' => 'field_5c4a0666c3bab',
                                'label' => 'Tekst',
                                'name' => 'text_content',
                                'type' => 'wysiwyg',
                                'instructions' => 'Het wordt afgeraden om in deze editor afbeeldingen in te voegen. Gebruik bij voorkeur het block "Afbeelding" hiervoor.',
                                'required' => 0,
                                'conditional_logic' => 0,
                                'wrapper' => array(
                                    'width' => '',
                                    'class' => '',
                                    'id' => '',
                                ),
                                'default_value' => '',
                                'tabs' => 'visual',
                                'toolbar' => 'full',
                                'media_upload' => 1,
                                'delay' => 0,
                            ),
                        ),
                        'min' => '',
                        'max' => '',
                    ),
```

When I create or edit a post I can see and use these fields.
Now I have a script to import posts and I want to add the field `Tekst (1 blok per rij)` as a new row programmatically.
I've tried using `add_sub_row` and `update_field` but none worked properly.

When I use `add_sub_row` like this I always get a return value of `false`:

```
add_sub_row([ 'field_5c4a0645c3baa', 1, 'field_5c4a0666c3bab'], [
    'field_5c4a0666c3bab' => 'test'
], $post)
```

When I use `update_field` I do get a response which makes it look like the field has been added, but I can't see it when I go to wp-admin and open the post:

```
update_field('field_5c4a0645c3baa', [
    'acf_fc_layout' => 'text',
    'text_content' => 'test'
], $post)
```

How should I use these methods? Because I've tried to use the manual of ACF for it but I don't really understand how to put it to use on flexible content.

Comment: did you try `add_row()` instead of sub row? or maybe `update_row()` ?

Comment: I really can't find any counterpart to get_row_layout, so this might be a question for the support page itself. But I have looked through the forum, and people have been asking this question for years.. So you might not get an answer there either.

Comment: related questions : https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/programmatically-adding-layouts-to-a-flexible-content-field/ - https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/programatically-adding-content-into-flex-content-fields/

Comment: - and overall support for flexible content : https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/forum/add-ons/flexible-content-field/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've contacted the ACF support.
They told me this:

> Thanks for reaching out to us.
>
> Unfortunately, I'm afraid it's not possible to add using the add_row
>   function with the flexible content field.
>
> However, you could implement a custom solution using the update_field
>   function to add sub_rows to the flexible content field.
>
> The developer already has it in his todo and probably this option will
>   be available in future updates.
>
> Apologies for the inconvenience.

Later they replied with this:

> Thanks for the follow up.
>
> Ideally, you need to load the field, modify the field values and
>   update the field using update_field.
>
> Kindly have a look at the following article from the support forums.
>
> https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/topic/issues-with-add_rows-and-flexible-content/
>
> Hope this helps.

The link helped me to create a new row in the flexible content.

Using this code:

```
$row_i = add_row(
    'field_55ce0e107c687', 
    [
        'acf_fc_layout' => 'headline', 
        'field_55df18296e4b3' => 'headline text'
    ],
    $ID
);
```

So I had to adjust it to my field names:

```
add_row(
    'field_5c4a0645c3baa', [
    'acf_fc_layout'       => 'text',
    'field_5c4a0666c3bab' => $block[ 'value' ],
], $post);
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: also if you want to add repeater row inside flexible content then,                                              
`$data[] = array( 
                    'field_5e7349062f311' => 'title 2',
                    'field_5e73490f2f312' => 'std pax 2',
                ); /* repeater */ 

 add_row('field_5e872ef537705', array( 'acf_fc_layout'=>'enter_rates','field_5e73527e242eb'=>'2023','field_5e7348c32f310'=>$data), 8374);`